# 'screen' [ctrl + a]+ k not working

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, session, lxqt

<kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> does nothing I've tried to get it to work but nothing happens no confirmation prompt shows at the bottom I looked up the file `.screenrc` and I'm considering changing the keys, but I would like to know why it's not working first.

I'm on a 2009 MBP currently running Lubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) LXQT version 0.17.0 on it, I have not changed the layout of my keys.

**Edit**: <kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> doesn't work either, but <kbd>Ctrl + a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> does, not sure why.

Comment: In what app?  Keyboard shortcuts are rather app/environment specific, so whilst LXQt shortcuts will work across LXQt apps & desktop, they won't the same for all apps (esp. if not LXQt/Qt5 or intended for other environments).  Also what *shortcuts* are you wanting to use; I don't see them at https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html

Comment: What is the version of `screen` that you are using?  `screen --version` and add it to your question.  Also, check if you are running in screen by running `ps -fp$PPID`.

Comment: @guiverc I was just informed on another forum that I needed to release the ctrl + a keys before pressing any others I had been holding down ctrol + a then pressing k while doing so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked this first [in Unix&Linux.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/749181/258991). Shortly put, here's the answer:

You need to first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then release those keys, then press <kbd>k</kbd> alone (or with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>k</kbd> is "destroy current window". But it only works if you have multiple windows in the first place.